# Null pointer java

Tags: java

I'm trying to open a directory get its name and load all the images from it. I'm getting a null pointer after the first system out print. What am I doing wrong? Is there also a better way to code this?

Here is my code:

```
public void open() {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    File studyPath = new File("C:\\");

    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(studyPath); 
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 

        // gets study path and sets study name
        studyPath = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        studyName = chooser.getName(studyPath);

        // get study images
        int x;
        int y;
        for(File i : studyPath.listFiles()) {
            try {
                FileInputStream file_input_stream = new FileInputStream(i);
                BufferedImage image_file = ImageIO.read(file_input_stream);

                x = image_file.getHeight();
                y = image_file.getWidth();

                int[] res = {x, y};

                StudyImage image = new StudyImage(i.getName(), res, image_file);
                System.out.println(image.toString());
                studyImages.add(image);  

            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Study.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
                            null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Study.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
                            null, ex);
            }  
        }

    }
}
```

But I get a null pointer after the first Sys out print line

Stack trace:

```
run:
Image name: ct_head01.jpg    Resolution: [I@5f85f4b7
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at medicalimageviewer.Study.open(Study.java:69)
    at medicalimageviewer.MedicalImageViewer.main(MedicalImageViewer.java:12)
Java Result: 1
```

What studyImage is:

```
private LinkedList<StudyImage> studyImages;
```

Comment: Where do you get that error? Show your stacktrace please

Comment: Where does `studyImages` come from? `StudyImages`, with a capital s, is not the same. `studyImages` is null, which is why you are getting the NPX. We need more information (like the code where `studyImages` comes from) before we can actually help you.

Comment: Can you show us the line where you initialise the `studyImages` variable please?

Comment: More important than your specific NullPointerException (or NPE) is to understand the process of debugging NPE's. You must check the variables that you dereference on the line that throws the NPE and see where you don't initialize them, when you think you do. If you did that, you'd at least know to show us where you think you initialize the `studyImages` variable, instead of making us beg for the code.

Comment: No, I said "initialise", not "declare".  Do you have a line where you set `studyImages` to something?  If you don't, that is almost certainly your problem.

Comment: Yep, you never initialize it.

Comment: By the way, `listFiles()` may give a folder too, and you're treating all elements as image files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private LinkedList<StudyImage> studyImages;
```

is *nothing*. This is the "declaration" which is just a pointer to where `studyImages` *will* go. It must be "initialized", as suggested by @Elliot Frisch. When you are calling

```
studyImages.add(image);
```

it's crashing with a `NullPointerException` because you are attempting to call a function on an object that *does not exist*.

Here's some more information:

- http://java.about.com/od/understandingdatatypes/a/declaringvars.htm
- https://www.google.com/search?q=variable+declaration+initialization+java

Answer (score 3):

Even though you didn't include it in your post, `studyImages` must not be initialized (`studyImages` is `null`).

```
// I suggest you use the interface type.
private List<StudyImage> studyImages = new LinkedList<StudyImage>();
// on java 7 and up, you could do
// private List<StudyImage> studyImages = new LinkedList<>();
// or
// private List<StudyImage> studyImages = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Ah this could be it let me check!

Comment: Accept in my case its new LinkedList<StudyImage>(). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell as the rest of your class is missing, but it could be that your `studyImages` variable is not initialized when you called it.

My advice is that it is best to initialize a variable right after you have declared it (there are some exceptions to this, such as initializing variables in a constructor), so if it is stored as a field, I would write: `List<StudyImage> studyImages = new ArrayList<StudyImage>();` if you have not already done this.