# How do I save the id from chatid with the telegram api

Tags: java

> Hello. I'm trying to solve this problem for a while now. For some
> reason I keep getting null pointer exception when  I try to save a
> object in my repository. Below you can see what happens and my
> functions.
>
> > java.lang.NullPointerException  at com.br.einstein.api.service.ApiTelegram.sendMsg(ApiTelegram.java:104)
> > at
> > com.br.einstein.api.service.ApiTelegram.onUpdateReceived(ApiTelegram.java:81)
> > at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)   at
> > org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27)
> > at
> > org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:317)
>
> ````
>        public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
>     
>        ApiEinstein api = new ApiEinstein();
>     
>        try {
>          JsonObject objSession = api.getSessionDetails();
>     
>          String message = update.getMessage().getText();
>          api.sendChatRequest(objSession);
>          List < String > list = new ApiEinstein().ReadChatDetails(objSession);
>     
>          sendMsg(update.getMessage().getChatId().toString(), list.toString());
>     
>          new ApiEinstein().SendChatMessage(objSession, message);
>          api.syncChatSession(objSession);
>        } catch (Exception e) {
>          e.printStackTrace();
>        }
>     
>      }
>     
>      public synchronized void sendMsg(String chatId, String s) {
>     
>        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
>        // sendMessage.enableMarkdown(true);
>        sendMessage.setChatId(chatId);
>        sendMessage.setText(s);
>     
>        long id = Long.valueOf(chatId);
>        Telegram telegram = new Telegram();
>        telegram.setChatId(id);
>     
>        repository.save(telegram);
>        try {
>     
>          execute(sendMessage);
>        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
>          e.printStackTrace();
>        }
>      } ```
> ````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Null pointer java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925178/null-pointer-java)